# Why so many cancelled projects on all freelancing websites?

Tags: negotiation

I am new to freelancing, I have just started with a new account on websites such as freelancer.com, oDesk and elance. I see that a major percentage of projects getting closed without any freelancer choosen. Why is it so?

Comment: Sorry, but this is asking for speculation, which is not suitable for our sites.

Comment: @Oded Actually, this is not speculation cause there are concrete reasons for that.

Comment: @PeterMV - be that as it may, the question is open-ended. There were several close reasons I could have chosen.

Comment: Many projects are closed or cancelled due to some of these reasons: client did not still choose the right guy (not urgent project), miscalculation of costs, client's client cancelled the project, client is unable to find a contractor that matches his budget or experience he seeks. A very few of these projects are ones created by other contractors who try to see how much would someone else charge for such project. If you read our topics, you will see why it's stupid idea to open such projects and to rely on other's estimation.

Comment: @Oded I was referring to the fact that there are indeed concrete reasons why many projects are closed or cancelled. I listed the main reasons. Very concrete ones.

Comment: Hey @PeterMV, if you feel strongly about this post, consider starting a [meta] discussion. It's possible we as a community could either get reopen support, or find ways to edit the post. Hope this helps.